# Alternatives to MEW for advanced users

Tags: wallets, myetherwallet, frontend

I am looking for an alternative to MyEtherWallet.

I am facing some issues with MEW, thus I am looking for alternative, preferably with more advanced functions - like for example allow me to "speed up" transaction, or that will not consider transaction over 750 seconds as failed (or even better, allow me edit nonce manually)

Beeing able to send raw transactions (vintage mew's "offline" mode) would be a great addition.

I'm not here to hate MEW, it's great project. It's just not for me.

Right now for my needs Im using mixture of localhost vintage mew, current mew, and raw javascript on web3js. It's not.. the most convinient setup, but I can get the work done.

I would appriciate remote node wallet, as I don't have enough storage to run local node.

All I need in terms of logging in is json keystore, or in case of Kovan I just have few plain priv keys for easier/faster testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can give MyCrypto (https://mycrypto.com) a try. It's a free and open source wallet interface, and has support for the features you mentioned:

- Changing the gas price, gas limit, nonce
- Signing transactions offline

If you use the desktop wallet, you can use your keystore (JSON) file or private keys too. You can download it from here: https://download.mycrypto.com. There is no need to run your own node, but you can do so if you want to in the future.

Comment: I used my crypto but I had some weird issues with it, that it was trying to send getter transactions. ( `"stateMutability":"view"` ). Admitably, MEW cannot handle ABI without now deprecated for long time `constant`. It might be my fault I haven't take a longer look around MyCrypto though. I will check it out tommorow more closely.

Comment: Great, this also allows me in normal "send ether" change message which will allow me to hand-craft requests when I need them, and allows very easy speed up operation or cancel operation, given I know what I am doing.